# How do you create multiple search in React and javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search

I don't know how to make multiple searches while I'm doing my assignment.
I'm trying a lot of things. If anyone knows, please answer.

- app.jsx

```
  const [touristSpot, setTouristSpot] = useState([]);
  const [filterTourlistSpot, setFilterTourlistSpot] = useState([]);
  const [searchItem, setSearchItem] = useState("");

const filedConfig = {
    method: "get",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/fields",
  };
  const recordConfig = {
    method: "get",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/records",
  };

  useEffect(
    () =>
      axios(filedConfig)
        .then((res) => console.log(res?.data))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err)),
    []
  );

  useEffect(
    () =>
      axios(recordConfig)
        .then((res) => setTouristSpot(res?.data))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err)),
    []
  );
  console.log(searchItem);
  useEffect(() => {
    setFilterTourlistSpot(() =>
      // touristSpot?.filter((spot) => spot.관광지명.includes(searchItem)) //first try
      // touristSpot?.filter((spot) => new RegExp(searchItem).test(spot.관광지명))//second try
      touristSpot?.filter((spot) => spot.관광지명.match(searchItem))//final try
    );
  }, [searchItem, touristSpot]);

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Search
        touristSpot={touristSpot}
        setTouristSpot={setTouristSpot}
        filterTouristSpot={filterTourlistSpot}
        setFilterTouristSpot={setFilterTourlistSpot}
        searchItem={searchItem}
        setSearchItem={setSearchItem}
      />
      <SpotList filterTourlistSpot={filterTourlistSpot} />
    </>
  );
```

- spotlist.jsx

```
const Spotlist = ({ filterTourlistSpot }) => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      {filterTourlistSpot.map((spot) => (
        <SearchSpot spot={spot} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

- searchspot.jsx

```
const Searchspot = ({ spot }) => {
  const onClick = (e) => {
    console.log(spot);
  };
  return (
    <div className={styles.spotbox} onClick={onClick}>
      <h3>{spot.관광지명}</h3>
    </div>
  );
};
```

What I want is to show you the search results that fit the keyword when you enter more than one keyword.
Together in the situation below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your details are a bit unclear, you should provide the errors you are getting, if any, and if possible a translation of the words that are not in english, since they seem to be used as variables and/or props.

If your error happens during the mapping in spotlist.jsx and everything else is working, then try this:

spotlist.jsx

```
const Spotlist = ({ filterTourlistSpot }) => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      {filterTourlistSpot().map((spot) => (
        <SearchSpot spot={spot} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

You forgot to call your `filterTourlistSpot` function before mapping the array returned from the filtering inside the body of that function.

If this does not solve your issue, please provide some more information about your problem and I will edit my answer to give a better solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is possible to produce a single result for the search now. But what I want is to get the search results for the two keywords when I enter them as shown in the picture above. In other words, when entering two keywords, we want to get two matching search results.

Comment: @byungju Hello, as mentioned, the details you provide are not enough to form a proper answer. Please provide more information, for example you might need to share your `Search` component, so that I can determine how you form your query before sending the request with Axios. The query is what determines the results, together with the capabilities of your backend API. If the API allows for multi keys in the query, then this can be done with one request, otherwise you need two (or more) concurrent requests.